# Hiding/Changing GIDSignInButton after signing in

Tags: ios, swift, google-oauth

So I'm pressing the `GIDSignInButton`, being taken through the sign in flow, but after the view controller is dismissed the button is still there with the same prompt: "Sign in". Well, I'm already signed in!

If my `func signIn` protocol is within my `appDel`, how can I hide or change the `GIDSignInButton` in a view controller after signing in?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I just spent some time with this and never found a good answer anywhere else. Turns out, there's no reason the `GIDSignInDelegate` implementation needs to be on the `AppDelegate`. I simply added sign in/out handlers on the `UIViewController` that hosts the signin button, and rearrange my view there.

```
class SettingsTableViewController: UITableViewController, LoginButtonDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if (error == nil) {
            //hide sign-in buttons, add sign-out button, etc
        }
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if (error == nil) {
            //show sign-in buttons, hide other stuff
        }
    }

    //similar methods for FBSDK signin, etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser` and determine if you need to display the Sign In button.

Another option is to hide or display the button in in the `GIDSignInDelegate` callback methods.

`GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()` will also trigger the delegate methods to indicate if silent sign on was successful or not.

```
class RecordingViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate {
    let googleSignInButton = GIDSignInButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupGoogleSignIn()
        // ...
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        // If error is nil, sign in was successful.
        googleSignInButton.isHidden = error == nil
    }

    func setupGoogleSignIn() {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.clientID = googleOAuthClientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signInSilently()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a work around to this 
Create a `.plist`( or use `NSUserDefault`) to contain all of your preferences 
add a boolean "signedIn" in your `.plist` and make is false.
-> when users successfully signin change the the "`signedIn`" value to true
when the the `viewController` that contains the google signin 
do this in viewDidLoad() is 
if "`signedIn`" is true then set the `GidButton.hidden = false`
else you want users to still sign in so do nothing

Comment: A for effort but this is a hard to maintain mysterious solution. Picture another developer coming in and trying to figure out what you did. Google returns an id_token and an access_token, that you can easily store in NSUserDefault or your own AuthenticationManager singleton class and you can just check and see if a valid, unexpired token exists for the user to hide the Google Sign In button